# Meteor: access user's name and profile_picture from the users collection by id

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

I have 2 collections in my project : Users & Topics

In the topics collection I have a 'createdBy' field that stores the '_id' of the user.

```
*Sample object*

{
  "_id": "SNj6C5fqMntSCaXdL",
  "opic": "Best Gaming Laptop",
  "tags": [
    "games",
    "technology",
    "product"
  ],
  "createdBy": "uzsMa4fZgmrrAD9ea",
  "createdAt": "2016-03-06T21:25:38.672Z"
}
```

In the users collection I have the fields'_id', 'name' and 'profile_picture_url' for every user.

```
{
  "_id": "uzsMa4fZgmrrAD9ea",
  "createdAt": "2016-03-03T03:48:05.787Z",
  "name": "Karan Sarin",
  "profile_picture_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/pro2_normal.jpg"
}
```

I am iterating over topics and showing a list of all topics and would like to show the profile picture and name of the creator.

```
{{#each topics}}
  <h2>{{topic_title}}<h2>
  *Profile picture here* *User's name here*
{{/each}}
```

P.S. I don't want to store the user's picture and name in the topics collection. Just want to access them from the user's collection when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to accomplish what you're after is to have the name as a part of the schema that gets stored to the topics when they're created. Then you can simply call {{name}} in your template. For your profile image you would want to create a custom variable in the template. Something like {{getProfileImage userId}}. Then write a template helper in a file like common.js to pull the profile image based on the userId.

Comment: The imageURL is in the users collection. Could you help me out with how exactly i can get the URL using only _id. What code do i write? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a helper function which returns the document of the user who created the topic. After that, you could use the `#with` expression to set the data context to the user document which corresponds to the current topic.

For example:

```
Template.topicsList.helpers({
    user: function () {
        return Users.findOne({_id: this.createdBy});
    }
});
```

---

```
<template name="topicsList">
    {{#each topics}}
        <h2>{{topic_title}}<h2>
            {{#with user}}
                <img src="{{profile_picture_url}}" alt="{{username}}">
                <strong>{{name}}</strong>
            {{/with}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Please pay attention that you subscribe also to the required documents in the `Users` collection.